# How to use the sort function in C++ 11 when dealing with C++ lists?

Tags: c++, c++11

This piece of code's purpose is to sort based on the second letter of a word. It worked when I passed using an array. However, it is not working with lists. Can anyone point me to the modification on where I can make it?

```
std::sort(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr),
        [](std::string l, std::string r){
            return l.substr(1) < r.substr(1);
        }
    );

    std::cout << "Sorted List: " << std::endl;
    for (auto const & s: arr) {
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "The End" << std::endl;
```

Comment: "Not working" is not a good enough description of the problem, [mcve] is.

Comment: Do you mean it doesn’t work with `std::list`? Because lists have their own [sort function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort).

Comment: Yes. It did work with arrays but not with std::list. Basically, I don't have any idea how to approach it. Appreciate it if you could show me.

Comment: `l.substr(1)` is a string with every character except the first. To sort on only the second character, `l[1] < r[1]`.

Comment: And what else if you could suggest?